# Why is my 64bit executable almost 3x larger than my 32bit executable?

Tags: c++builder

I made a simple Hello World program with nothing but a Form and a Label that says "Hello World!".  I build the project with C++ Builder, first as 64bit then as 32bit.

The 64bit executable is `8,568 KB`.  In contrast, the 32bit executable is only `2,979 KB`.

Why?

For both projects, I disabled `Link with runtime packages`, `Enable RTTI`, `Debug Information`, and `Link with Dynamic RTL`.

Both projects are set to `Release` mode.

The version of C++ Builder is:

```
Embarcadero® C++Builder 10.3 Version 26.0.36039.7899
Update 3
```

Comment: 3x is a bit extreme, yes. One thing to consider is pointers are 2x the size in 64bit, and there is a lot of pointer usage in the RTL/VCL. But only pointers used in static data should affect the EXE size. Like pointers used in RTTI. Even though you disable RTTI, that only affects your own code, not the RTL/VCL which had its own RTTI you can't disable otherwise DFM streaming for the Form would not work. But also, depending on which version of C++Builder you are using, the 64bit RTL/VCL may simply not be as optimized as the 32bit RTL/VCL, which can also affect the EXE size.

Comment: I edited my post to add version info, I recently downloaded it so I believe it's the latest.

Comment: Some bloat might be caused by rework of Windows SEH for x86_64 compared to x86 - compiler now has to generate unwind tables. I think Borland product are traditionally tightly intergrated with SEH.

Comment: @StaceyGirl Yes, C++Builder uses SEH exception handling on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ Builder had stripped the symbols from the 32bit `.exe` but not the 64bit one.

I ran `strip helloworld.exe` on my 64bit `.exe`and it reduced the filesize down from `8,568 KB` to `6,358 KB`.

This same command didn't affect the size of the 32bit `.exe`.